# In Python 2.7, how should I check if I can use the `in` keyword to see if an object contains an item?

Tags: python

Before performing a test like

```
if something in the_object:
    ...
```

I would like to test if it's safe to use the `in` keyword on `the_object`.   I believe that `in` will work in this usage if `the_object` has one of several methods such as `__contains__` and `__iter__`.

Is there a test similar to the following I can use, but that checks for compatibility with `in` instead of containing `__iter__`?

```
import collections

if isinstance(the_object, collections.Iterable):
    if something in the_object:
        ...
```

Or should I just

```
try:
    if something in the_object:
        ...
except TypeError:
    # move on
```

Comment: use the try-except...

Comment: In python a common practice is EAFP, or it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission, go with the `try...except`

Comment: So, from the data-model docs, "For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`" so there would be *three* checks you'd have to do to be exhaustive. So yeah, just EAFP

Comment: More details: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I have made this answer a CW post simply to mark this question as answered. The real credit goes to juanpa.arrivillaga and Nick A, in the comments.*

### It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission

`in` looks to see of an object contains `__contains__()` first, then looks for `__iter__()`, then finally looks for `__getitem__()`. While you could check for each of them, doing a `try...except` would allow `in` to do it for you, or to error if it can't.

Here's the section that juanpa.arrivillaga linked to:

### 6.10.2. Membership test operations

The operators `in` and `not in` test for membership. `x in s` evaluates to `True` if *x* is a member of *s*, and `False` otherwise. `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`. All built-in sequences and set types support this as well as dictionary, for which in tests whether the dictionary has a given key. For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

For the string and bytes types, `x in y` is `True` if and only if *x* is a substring of *y*. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

For user-defined classes which define the `__contains__()` method, `x in y` returns `True` if `y.__contains__(x)` returns a true value, and `False` otherwise.

For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z` with `x == z` is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.

Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index *i* such that `x == y[i]`, and all lower integer indices do not raise IndexError exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if `in` raised that exception).

The operator `not in` is defined to have the inverse true value of `in`.